# Receiving Error "member function must be called or its address taken in function" in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program to do various things with a struct array, and I'm having trouble with the functions. I keep getting error E2235 "Member function must be called or its address taken in function read(student *, int)" and I'm not really sure what's causing this error. My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <fstream>
struct student{
    string first;
    string last;
    string id;
    double GPA;
    int age;
};
void menu();
void read(student* data, int x);
int main(){

bool quit=false;
char choice;
student data[20];
cout<<"Welcome!"<<endl;
//the program is menu driven, so a switch statement allows for many choices
while(!quit){
    menu();
    cin>>choice;
    switch(choice){
        case '1': read(data, 20); break;
        case '2': break;
        case '3': break;
        case '4': break;
        case '5': break;
        case '6': break;
        case '7': break;
        case '8': cout<<endl<<"Goodbye!\n"; quit=true; break;
        default: cout<<"I think you're doing it wrong. Please try again.";
        }
    }
} 

//menu output so the user knows what they're doing
void menu(){
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"What would you like to do?"<<endl;
    cout<<"(1) - Read data into the database"<<endl;
    cout<<"(2) - Add a student"<<endl;
    cout<<"(3) - Remove a student"<<endl;
    cout<<"(4) - List all students"<<endl;
    cout<<"(5) - Compute the average GPA and SD of the database"<<endl;
    cout<<"(6) - View Student Information"<<endl;
    cout<<"(7) - Save the database"<<endl;
    cout<<"(8) - Exit"<<endl;
}

//the problem function
void read(student* data, int x){
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("StudentStruct.txt");
    int k=0;
    string first, last, id;
    double GPA;
    int age;
    while(!infile.eof&&k<x){
        infile>>first;
        data[k].first;
        infile>>last;
        data[k].last;
        infile>>id;
        data[k].id;
        infile>>GPA;
        data[k].GPA;
        infile>>id;
        data[k].age;
        k++;
    }
    cout<<"The database now contains "<<k<<" data entries from 'StudentStruct.txt'"<<endl;
}
```

What could be causing this error, and how should I fix it?

Comment: which compiler (looks like VS, right)? What line is the error on? Can you produce a smaller example of the problem?

Comment: `eof` should be `eof()`. Actually, it shouldn't be there at all.

Comment: @chris wow, I feel stupid for not catching that, thanks.

BTW, why do you say it shouldn't be there at all?

Comment: @Mike, Because `while (!eof())` is wrong. You should only proceed with the body if the current read is successful. This is typically done with something like `while (infile >> a)`.

Comment: What line is it located at? Why are you calling the structs mems without doing anything with them?

Comment: That won't make a difference. Either way, it will be passed in as a pointer.

Comment: Have you fixed the problems yet?

Comment: Why the obsolete `<iostream.h>` instead of the standard `<iostream>`?

Comment: @chris while you may technically be correct, I think that's *slightly* pedantic.

Comment: @NikBougalis, Not when you start getting bugs that look like they have nothing to do with that line.

Comment: That's a fair point. I updated my answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Writing in Textpad, compiling with Borderlands. Somewhere in there, the .h is necessary.

I think.

I did not have the best instruction.

Comment: If you are using `<fstream>`, you should be using `<iostream>` (without `.h` suffix).  It you are using `<iostream.h>`, you should use `<fstream.h>`.  The suffixed names are pre-standard. (Was there `<fstream.h>` before the standard?  I don't recall.)  But the unsuffixed names are standard, and you really shouldn't be writing new code using the pre-standard library.

Comment: Would the compiler complain when mixing pre and post standard header files?

Comment: @Frank I receive a compile error, something along the lines of not finding header file. I don't remember the exact error though, just that it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I would break the problem function into a couple of separate pieces. One would *just* read a single "record" from the file. The other would use that to read all the records. The first, by convention, is named `operator>>` (aka a "stream extractor):

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &infile, student &d) { 
    infile >> d.first;
    infile >> d.last;
    infile >> d.id;
    infile >> d.GPA;
    infile >> d.age;
    return infile;
}
```

The second function uses that one to read all the data from the file. For it, you do *not* want to use `while (!whatever.eof())` -- that's pretty much guaranteed to fail. There are a couple of alternatives. One is like:

```
while (infile >> some_student)
    students.push_back(some_student);
```

Another possibility is to use an `istream_iterator`, which can pretty much automate the whole loop:

```
std::vector<student> students((std::istream_iterator<student>(infile)),
                                std::istream_iterator<student>());
```

That defines the `students` vector, and initializes it from the pair of `istream_iterator`s, which implicitly loops through the file, reading all the data (using the stream extractor from up above.

As that implies, I'd also use `std::vector<student>` (if possible) instead of `student *`, so it can be resized when/if needed to accommodate the data. Using those, the function becomes something like this:

```
std::vector<student> read() { 
    std::ifstream infile("StudentStruct.txt");
    std::vector<student> students((std::istream_iterator<student>(infile)),
                                    std::istream_iterator<student>());
    return students;
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Personally, I'd probably prefer `operator>>` to contain `return infile >> d.first >> d.last >> d.id >> d.GPA >> d.age;` instead of 6 separate lines. That's my opinion, however, and I'm just throwing it out there.

Comment: @chris: Actually, I probably would too -- but I tried to follow how his code was written as closely as possible and still work.

Comment: Fair enough. Keeping things as recognizable as possible is usually a good strategy.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is an awkwardly worded error message related to the code inside the `while` condition, with the `infile.eof`. You are not using the function-call convention (i.e. `infile.eof()`) and so the compiler doesn't know what you are trying to do with that code: call the member function or take the its address. So it throws up a warning.

There's also another issue with the way you read student data from the file:

```
string first, last, id;
double GPA;
int age;

while(!infile.eof&&k<x){
    // Here you read a string into the local variable 'first'
    infile>>first;

    // And here you do... what? referencing the 'first' member variable of the k'th student.
    data[k].first;

    // Rinse, lather repeat
    infile>>last;
    data[k].last;
    infile>>id;
    data[k].id;
    infile>>GPA;
    data[k].GPA;
    infile>>id;
    data[k].age;
    k++;
}
```

Look carefully at what you are doing: your `data` is never populated with students. You read values into local variables and then throw the results away, never using them. Integrating chris' suggestion about eliminating the use of `infile.eof()` try this instead:

```
while((k < x) && (infile >> data[k].first)) 
{
    infile >> data[k].last;
    infile >> data[k].id;
    infile >> data[k].GPA;
    infile >> data[k].age;

    k++;
}
```